# I don't know how to export a matrix from CUDA

Tags: cuda, save

I have a program that computes inside a kernel all the variables that I need to export for each instant of time. However, The current execution of the code includes opening, writing and closing a .txt which is translated in 3 and half minutes per document. In total,

I need to produce more than 200 documents in total. I was wondering if there exist a more efficient way to export the data (.dat, .mat...) in CUDA.

I upload also the code use for the .txt generation:

```
fprintf (f,"%-2.3f\t",myData);
```

where f is the document and myData saved as a float.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: CUDA does not have any support for user space disk I/O. If you need faster output you probably need to use an optimized library. But 200 x 3 = 600 minutes, which is basically overnight. Put it on in the evening, wake up in the morning, and it is finished. That will be far less time than it takes to find and add some sort of accelerated I/O system

Comment: Of course, but this the issue of your programming language rather than Cuda. Use binary encodings rather than text outputs, it will be way faster